# Проблема с пакетом matplotlib в проекте на pythone 3.6: импорт в PyCharm ведёт к AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'verbose'

Tags: python, mac, pycharm

Возникла проблема. Работаю на `Mac os 10.13.3`, среда `PyCharm Professional 2017.3. Python 3.6`

При компиляции данной программы:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([2, 5, -6, 7, 4, 3, 8, 9, 1, -2], dtype=float)
y = np.array([-1, 77, -297, 249, 33, 9, 389, 573, -3, -21],  dtype=float)


def lagranz(x, y, t):
    z = 0
    for j in range(len(y)):
        p1 = 1
        p2 = 1
        for i in range(len(x)):
            if i == j:
                p1 = p1 * 1
                p2 = p2 * 1
            else:
                p1 = p1 * (t - x[i])
                p2 = p2 * (x[j] - x[i])
        z = z + y[j] * p1 / p2
    return z

xnew = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 100)
ynew = [lagranz(x, y, i) for i in xnew]

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, ynew)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Компилятор выдает такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Korotkihvm/PycharmProjects/TheLagrangeInterpolationPolynomial/method.py", line 2, in <module>
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/Users/Korotkihvm/PycharmProjects/TheLagrangeInterpolationPolynomial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
  _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
File "/Users/Korotkihvm/PycharmProjects/TheLagrangeInterpolationPolynomial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
  [backend_name], 0)
File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend/backend_interagg.py", line 17, in <module>
  verbose = matplotlib.verbose
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'verbose'
```

Кто может подсказать в чем проблема?

Comment: говорят, что подобная проблема возникает при использовании `matplotlib 2.2.0`. Для решения проблемы попробуйте удалить версию `2.2.0` и установите `2.1.2`

Comment: @stxdtm благодарю за помощь, действительно помогло

Comment: @stxdtm, может оформите как ответ? тогда вопрос не будет висеть без ответа и в поисковиках будет видно что есть ответ на вопрос...

Comment: @MaxU, оформил в виде ответа

Comment: @ВикторКоротких, если вам дали исчерпывающий ответ - [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Починили в [PyCharm 2018.1 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/).

Answer (score 3):

Данная проблема связана с тем, что в новой версии `matplotlib` сломали обратную совместимость (например, как раз удалили `matplotlib.verbose`). Соответственно, все приложения, в списке зависимостей которых есть `matplotlib`, могут столкнуться с данной проблемой.

Сейчас практически везде рекомендуют не дожидаться официальных исправлений, а установить одну из предыдущих версий `matplotlib`. Например, `2.1.2`. Сделать это можно с помощью `pip`:

```
 pip uninstall matplotlib
 pip install matplotlib==2.1.2
```